# Intent filter for custom pathPattern

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, intentfilter

I have this intent filter to open files with extension "custom" in my app:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

    <data android:scheme="content" />
    <data android:host="*" />
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />

    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.custom" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.custom" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.custom" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.custom" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.custom" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.custom" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.custom" />

</intent-filter>
```

In this case file opens well:
[image]

But in this case it doesn't open:
[image]

Also it works well when opening file from Telegram chat.

How can I open my custom files from anywhere?

**UPD**

I've added pdf mime-type for tests. It opens pdf files from everywhere. Here are the intents I got:

- for download folder (works with custom extension): `Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.google.android.apps.nbu.files.provider/1/file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/Untitled.pdf typ=application/pdf flg=0x13000001 cmp=team.sls.testapp/.ActivityMain }`
- for Telegram (works with custom extension): `Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://org.telegram.messenger.provider/media/Telegram/Telegram Documents/2_5276292126848585208.pdf typ=application/pdf flg=0x13000001 cmp=team.sls.testapp/.ActivityMain }`
- for downloads folder in second image (doesn't work with custom extension): `Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.google.android.apps.nbu.files.provider/2/1863 typ=application/pdf flg=0x13000001 cmp=team.sls.testapp/.ActivityMain }`
- for opening from Dowdload manager from notification panel (doesn't work with custom extension): `Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/1508 typ=application/pdf flg=0x13000003 cmp=team.sls.testapp/.ActivityMain }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I open my custom files from anywhere?

There is no way to open custom files from anywhere.

[@CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) helped me to figure out the reason in my [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67638455/what-is-com-google-android-apps-nbu-files-provider-2).

The problem is that `Uri` values in `Intents` do not have file extensions.

What are the alternatives? We can use standard `application/`*{whatever}* mime-type to open files in our application. But we have to select "Open with..." menu item in file explorer then.