# What is com.google.android.apps.nbu.files.provider/2?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, intentfilter, android-fileprovider

I've opened pdf file from different sources and got this `Intents`:

1. File manager (Google Files) -> Internal storage -> Download: `Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.google.android.apps.nbu.files.provider/1/file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/Untitled.pdf typ=application/pdf flg=0x13000001 cmp=team.sls.testapp/.ActivityMain }`
2. File manager (Google Files) -> Downloads: `Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.google.android.apps.nbu.files.provider/2/1863 typ=application/pdf flg=0x13000001 cmp=team.sls.testapp/.ActivityMain }`
3. Dowdload manager (from notification panel): `Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/1508 typ=application/pdf flg=0x13000003 cmp=team.sls.testapp/.ActivityMain }`
4. Telegram chat: `Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://org.telegram.messenger.provider/media/Telegram/Telegram Documents/2_5276292126848585208.pdf typ=application/pdf flg=0x13000001 cmp=team.sls.testapp/.ActivityMain }`

What is `content://com.google.android.apps.nbu.files.provider/2/1863` and why the path to same file is different?
But more interesting - why cases 1 and 4 can open files with custom extensions but 2 and 3 don't?

If there is a misunderstanding with cases 1 and 2, take a look to screenshots in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67615728/intent-filter-for-custom-pathpattern)

Comment: "But more interesting - why cases 1 and 4 can open files with custom extensions but 2 and 3 don't?" -- their `Uri` values do not have file extensions. This is one of the many reasons why custom file extensions have never worked well in Android.

Comment: @CommonsWare, so it isn't any way to open files with custom file extensions from everywhere? Mechanisms of standard mime-types for applications are not available to us?

Comment: "so it isn't any way to open files with custom file extensions from everywhere?" -- correct. This is no different than the Web, where a URL does not need to have any particular file extension. "Mechanisms of standard mime-types for applications are not available to us?" -- common MIME types are fine. For example, all four of those would work fine if, instead of filtering on an extension, you filtered on the `application/pdf` MIME type.

Answer (score 0):

All these four Uri's are following the same pattern

```
content://com.google.android.apps.nbu.files.provider/1/file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/Untitled.pdf
content://com.google.android.apps.nbu.files.provider/2/1863
content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/1508
content://org.telegram.messenger.provider/media/Telegram/Telegram Documents/2_5276292126848585208.pdf
```

content://`PACKAGE_NAME`.provider/`CONTENT_DETAIL`

- Obviously the `PACKAGE_NAME` depends on application.
- And the `CONTENT_DETAIL` is optional, either file_id or full_path.

If you decompile all these four applications and look at their `AndroidManifest.xml` you will see the same provider tag with minor differences.

Look at Google Files's AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application>
  <provider 
    android:name="com.google.android.libraries.storage.storagelib.FileProvider" 
    android:exported="false" 
    android:authorities="com.google.android.apps.nbu.files.provider" 
    android:grantUriPermissions="true"/>
</application>
```

This provider will generate the `HierarchicalUri`'s like bellow
`content://com.google.android.apps.nbu.files.provider/1651/2`

Using the snippet bellow, you can read file/content from all those four application's.

```
public final class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      Intent intent = getIntent();
      InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(intent.getData());
      String content = new String(Utils.unwrap(is));
      Log.i("TAG", "content: " + content);
   }

   public static byte[] unwrap(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int nRead;
        byte[] data = new byte[4096];
        while ((nRead = is.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
            baos.write(data, 0, nRead);
        }
        baos.flush();
        is.close();
        baos.close();
        return baos.toByteArray();
   }
}
```

I hope i have answered your question.